# how to create custom transition animation that moves the view whole, when a button is tapped?

Tags: swift, transition, custom-transition

**I hope to create a specific custom transition animation for a button
that grows in size** 
to fill center of the screen overlaying the previous ViewController.

*luckily I've even found how I want it to look like!* ([Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KmlB.gif)))

I'm new to coding so I know this is something I shouldn't get into,
but I wanted to give it a go
and unlike in the reference, I planned to put just one textField & a button inside -
but it seems like I've been digging the wrong hole.

The overall animation doesn't look great either with the background visible (even with .clear)
to add on, I played around with much of the numbers...
here's a gif of what I made
([*Test Animation*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8LKg.gif))

**Is there any way to salvage pieces of my code to recreate like the one in the reference?

 and if it's not view (from my today's experience...) what would be a way to create it?**

here's what I've done so far

##### ---- Presenter ----

```
class Presenter: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    private let transition = Transition()

    func present(_ viewController: UIViewController, from parent: UIViewController) {
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        viewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        parent.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                             presenting: UIViewController,
                             source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.direction = .present
        return transition
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        transition.direction = .dismiss
        return transition
    }
}
```

##### ---- Transition ----

```
class Transition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum Direction {
        case present
        case dismiss
    }
    
    var direction: Direction = .present
    private var presentedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    private var dismissedConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval { 0.7 }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        switch direction {
        case .present:
            present(using: transitionContext)
        case .dismiss:
            dismiss(using: transitionContext)
        }
    }

    private func present(using context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let presentedView = context.view(forKey: .to) else {
            context.completeTransition(false)
            return
        }

        context.containerView.addSubview(presentedView)
        presentedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        presentedConstraints = [
            presentedView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
            presentedView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
            presentedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.topAnchor),
            presentedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.centerYAnchor, constant: 170)
        ]

        dismissedConstraints = [
            presentedView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 80),
            presentedView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.rightAnchor, constant: -80),
            presentedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.topAnchor, constant: 400),
            presentedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: context.containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -30)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(dismissedConstraints)

        context.containerView.setNeedsLayout()
        context.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(dismissedConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(presentedConstraints)


        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: context),
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0,
            options: .curveEaseInOut,
            animations: {
                context.containerView.setNeedsLayout()
                context.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: { _ in
                context.completeTransition(true)
            })
    }

    private func dismiss(using context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(presentedConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(dismissedConstraints)

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: context),
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0,
            options: .curveEaseInOut,
            animations: {
                context.containerView.setNeedsLayout()
                context.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: { _ in
                context.completeTransition(true)
            })
    }
}
```

and finally just the 2nd VC that has the view!

#### ---- 2nd VC ----

```
protocol MessageViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func messageViewController(_ vc: MessageViewController, didSaveTodo: Todo)
}

class MessageViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: MessageViewControllerDelegate?
    var todo: Todo?

    let messageView = UIView()
    let sendButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        view.addSubview(messageView)
        view.addSubview(sendButton)
        
        sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sendButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        sendButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(save), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        messageView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        messageView.layer.cornerRadius = 180/2
        messageView.clipsToBounds = true
        messageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Save was tapped.")
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```